# Regular expression and Obsolete attribute extraction in NDepend

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, ndepend, cqlinq

I've tried to search on the NDepend documentation if there is any possible way to do a regex on Obsolete Attributes?

And is there a way to get the Obsolete attribute in NDepend at all? Any ideas or example of code on how to make a small Linq query to get an attribute of an obsolete?

For example:

`//TODO! I WANT THE STRING USING NDepend!
ObsoleteAttribute["Deprecated in 2007-01-23!"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NDepend you can get the attribute type,the methods/types/assemblies... tagged with the attribute, but you cannot get the string in the attribute. Much better than reflection, we'd advise using the framework [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) for that.